# Matrix - Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: errors, matrices

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 

1 && 1 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\

0 && 0 && 1 && 1 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\

0 && 1 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 1 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\

0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 1 \\

0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\

0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\

1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\

1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\

1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: instead of providing lots of empty columns (presumably to increase the separation between "real" columns, right?), it would be much more efficient if you (a) replaced all instances of `&&` with `&` and (b) issued the command `\setlength\arraycolsep{10pt}`. A side benefit of the approach recommended here would be that you wouldn't have to increase the value of the counter variable `MaxMatrixCols` -- at least, not the the `pmatrix` at hand.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Is there any reason that cells are separated by  `&&`, not a single `&`? In short, is each other column empty?

Comment: @Mico tex removes empty columns so if you use `&&` in every row it doesn't increase space

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - My apologies for not expressing myself well. I was comparing (after running `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{17}`, of course) the outputs of (a) `$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 1 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 00 \end{pmatrix}$` and (b) `\setlength\arraycolsep{10pt}$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$`. These `pmatrix` environments have the same width -- a result that isn't changed by having more rows of the type shown in the OP's example.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

number of columns in your matrix exceed default value (10). it can be enlarged for example to 20 columns by adding

```
 \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
```

in preamble. why you need empty columns?